# override the track.phtml template

Tags: module, overrides

I would like to override this file in my module but cannot find the reference name for

```
base/default/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <????>
        <reference name="????">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>namespace/email/order/shipment/track.phtml</template>
           </action>
        </reference>
    </????>
</layout>
```

what should i be replacing the question marks with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured out I added to mmy modules config

```
<global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <sales_email_shipment_template translate="label" module="sales">
                <label>New Shipment</label>
                <file>sales/[namespace]/shipment_new.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </sales_email_shipment_template>
            <sales_email_shipment_guest_template translate="label" module="sales">
                <label>New Shipment for Guest</label>
                <file>sales/[namespace]/shipment_new_guest.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </sales_email_shipment_guest_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

and then copied the core files to my namespace and edited the block that called track.phtml to call my custom module

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

This template `email/order/shipment/track.phtml` is used directly in email (app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/shipment_new.html & app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/shipment_new_guest.html). 
`{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}`

So you can't use layout to change this template. You need to create a transactional email to change this template.

Hope this help,

Comment: I want this to be in a module that i can place on any site and it will change the email template I dont think your idea would be able to do that

Comment: no other method that I know (@SeStro and mine).
So, you can do : rewrite `core/template` and if the template is `email/order/shipment/track.phtml` change it by your own. It works but this is a very dirty code

Comment: i dont mind dirty, but i am a beginner how would i do the  rewrite core/template ?

Comment: how do I rewrite core/template

Comment: If you want to do a module for the community, so do not think like this. Clean code is important. Your module need to create a transactional email with the good template.
If not, the solution from @SeStro or mine is the only way to do that.

Comment: thank you for the help is there a way add to my module some code to override those templates?

Answer (score 0):

Just create file in `[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml`

Comment: I want this to be in a module that i can place on any site and it will change the email template I dont think your idea would be able to do that