# Override track.phtml

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.3

Before marking as duplicate go through once

I'm facing issue with overriding `module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml`

**I'm using Magento 2.3.3**

Answer is here but its not working. [Overriding track.phtml in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292834/overriding-track-phtml-in-magento2)

I can able to override within my theme but I want some customization I would like to override with module.

I tried below:

> Vendor_Module/view'frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="sales_email_order_shipment_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sales.order.email.shipment.track" template="Vendor_Module::email/shipment/track.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="tracking_url" xsi:type="object">Magento\Sales\Block\DataProviders\Email\Shipment\TrackingUrl</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

I tried wrapping block within `referenceContainer='content'` but still not working.

**UPDATE**

**Make sure you check send email copy to customer while generating shipment.**

NO solution worked for me provided in comments. Any other solutions ?

But doesn't seems to work for me. Any ideas ?

Comment: The solution you implemented worked fine for me. Make sure you copied the "email/shipment/track.phtml" template into your extension "templates" folder and also try to regenerate the "pub/static/" content by performing a deploy.

Comment: comment <update handle="sales_email_order_shipment_renderers"/> this from your layout and check

Comment: If your issue is overriding template in module, have you tried, <action method="setTemplate">

in xml?

Comment: try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/308043/magento-2-override-core-template-in-own-module

Comment: @AlexConstantinescu I did have you tried with Magento 2.3.3 CE and make sure while generating shipment you check "Email copy to customer". yes I copied template to my module also but not working.

Comment: @Msquare I tried by commenting update handle and also tried with setTemplate method but still not working, have you tried in your project adn its working for you !!?

Comment: @Korbin Yes man I tried with setTemplate method also but no luck can you verify once if that works for you !?

Comment: Are you targeting the correct "name" and hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment, don't post much on Magento Exchange. I read through the comments. Have you read through this ticket? Make sure if you are doing a hard override you are properly including track.phtml. You might consider doing what they did and do a hard override.
[override the track.phtml template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91865/override-the-track-phtml-template)

Comment: Yes, I did same thing copied file to exact location as defined in my custom layout. What's that xml part that I didn't get.