# Magento 2 - Override core template in own module

Tags: magento2, module, template, magento2.3.4

I want to override the template **Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml** in my own module.

At the moment the override is in my theme:

**app/design/frontend/company/base/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml**

but I need it in my module:

**app/code/company/customer/???**

Is this possible?

---

I am developing a module which is adding a **new field** in the **customer register form.**

I need the override in my module, otherwise users would have to add my module and also modify their theme.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will have to override customer_account_create.xml in your own module.

So create "customer_account_create.xml" file in app\code\Your_module_vendor\Your_module_name\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_create.xml

And add below code into it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VENDOR_MODULE::form/register.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
</page>
```

Now create your register.phtml in app\code\Your_module_vendor\Your_module_name\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml

Please upvote if it works. Thanks!